# jQuery code not passing special characters properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jeditable

I have a site that uses the jQuery jEditable plugin (inline editing via AJAX). Thing is, if you enter something like "Entrées" (this is for editing restaurant menus, so such input should be expected), the AJAX PHP script that gets the value instead receives "EntrÃ©es". How can I ensure the value being sent is sent properly?

What's even more weird is that the database value is stored as "EntrÃ©es", but when displayed on the web page, it displays "Entrées" properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have solved the problem. Using escape() instead of encodeURI() worked properly. Anybody know why that would be?

escape() returned: Entr%E9es

encodeURI() returned: Entr%C3%A9es

Very strange.

Comment: escape works for ascii characters but if ever want to send characters outside ascii range you have to use encodeURI and uridecode it on server-side. this has nothing to do with your page or code, its because your ajax (get) parameters are sent as a url query string and that has its own rules.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure not only the form where the text is entered but also the page where it's displayed use UTF8 encoding. If your "testing" to see what's received is a simple `echo ...; exit;` it's likely that this page is not rendered as UTF8.

Comment: I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the header. Is that sufficient? Should I also use PHP to set the header's charset as well? (By the way, I'm having the AJAX script output the raw input received directly into a .txt file, and it's still showing "EntrÃ©es".)

Comment: Headers sent from the servers are usually better and some browsers use them if they are available even if the file contains a different one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript encodeURI() function on your string before you send it.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do that in the context of jEditable? The documentation is a bit shoddy and incomplete. I have to search through the comments for information that's more helpful than the documentation itself. :P

Comment: I figured it out (just edited the source JS file itself). However, now the input recieved is "Entr%C3%A9es", which is the same as "EntrÃ©es". WTH is going on?>

Comment: I was just going to say that:) ok now on server side use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx

Comment: Using urldecode() (PHP) only produces "EntrÃ©es", as I mentioned in my comment above yours (Entr%C3%A9es = EntrÃ©es). See my answer below. Using escape() client-side (before sending user input) produced the correct value (Entr%E9es = Entrées), while encodeURI() didn't.